# how to guard against an Implicitly Unwrapped Optional causing an "unexpectedly found nil" error with Firebase and then give it a value

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am getting the error Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value at my line

```
 let pictureRef = self.actStorage.child("\(user.uid).jpg")
```

I know that this is caused by implicitly trying to unwrap an optional which is my

```
     var actStorage: StorageReference!
```

my question is how would I use optional binding or a guard statement so that it is no longer nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Swift can compile the code without inserting an implicit unwrap, it does so. You can change the code so it doesn't need an implicit unwrap:

```
guard let pictureRef = self.actStorage?.child("\(user.uid).jpg") else {
    return
}
```

However, it might be better to change the type of `actStorage` to an explicit optional (`StorageReference?`) instead, if you can change the type.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That has fixed the issue with my code crashing, however it does not continue after because the value must still be nil so it executes the else return. How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: That I do not know, as I do not have any experience with Firebase. I did not think you needed a Firebase-specific answer. You should edit your question to include the code that uses Firebase to give `actStorage` a value.

Comment: Perhaps it is just a matter of adding a `didSet` observer to `actStorage` that calls whatever method needs to use it. Make sure to async-dispatch back to the main queue if it might be set on a background thread.

Comment: So i did a bit of digging, I was able to fix the issue by simply changing my var actStorage: StorageReference! to Let actStorage = Storage.storage().reference() and it worked with my original let pictureRef = self.actStorage.child("\(user.uid).jpg")

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
if let pictureRef = self.actStorage?.child("\(user.uid).jpg") {
  // pictureRef exists 
} else {
  // picutreRef nill
}
```